# Is C# Exam 70-483 reference book example wrong? (Parent/Child threads)

Tags: c#, .net, task

In the first edition of the [C# 70-483 Exam Ref](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/store/exam-ref-70-483-programming-in-c-sharp-mcsd-9780735676824), Example 1-12 gives an example of attaching child tasks to parent tasks.  I believe it to be in error and wanted someone to check my understanding before continuing under this assumption.  The code in the example is as follows:

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Chapter1
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Task<Int32[]> parent = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var results = new Int32[3];

                new Task(() => results[0] = 0, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent).Start();
                new Task(() => results[1] = 1, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent).Start();
                new Task(() => results[2] = 2, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent).Start();

                return results;
            });


            var finalTask = parent.ContinueWith(parentTask =>
            {
                foreach (var i in parentTask.Result)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                }
            });

            finalTask.Wait();
        }

    }
}
```

The issue is with `Task.Run`.  [MSDN explains](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/10/24/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/) that this does *not* allow child tasks to be attached.  I thought this may be an issue with .NET versions at the time of publication (2013) but the MSDN article was published two years prior to the book.

This is particularly tricky because if the code above is executed, the `results` array *does indeed* get its values set to 0, 1, and 2.  However, if the lambda does anything more time-consuming than this, no value is set at that index in the array.

For example, the code below assigns "one" and "two" to `results` elements 1 and 2, respectively, but element 0 is null.

```cs
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Chapter1
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Task<String[]> parent = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var results = new String[3];

                new Task(() => {
                    SHA256 mySHA256 = SHA256.Create();
                    byte[] messageBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("asdf");
                    byte[] hashBytes = mySHA256.ComputeHash(messageBytes);
                    results[0] = BitConverter.ToString(hashBytes).Replace("-", "");
                }, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent).Start();

                new Task(() => results[1] = "one", TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent).Start();
                new Task(() => results[2] = "two", TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent).Start();

                return results;
            });


            var finalTask = parent.ContinueWith(parentTask =>
            {
                foreach (var i in parentTask.Result)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                }
            });

            finalTask.Wait();
        }

    }
}
```

When I start the parent task using the task factory (not shown in examples), everything works as expected and the `TaskCreationOptions` affect the synchronization of child threads.

So my questions are:

1. Am I correct in my understanding that it's meaningless to pass `TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent` into a child task created under `Thread.Run`?
2. Is my assumption correct that the book's example only works because the child task lambdas are simply performing assignments which happen to complete before the parent thread is terminated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe both your questions (assertions) are correct. [This MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/attached-and-detached-child-tasks) article seems to cover it pretty well.

Re 2, as the article says, passing `AttachedToParent` to a task started with `Task.Run()` yields "unpredictable" results, one of which would be the ones you observe.

I should add a nuance, which is that the "child" tasks will continue running after the `ContinueWith()` begins, so they get (a tiny bit of) extra time to complete before their corresponding `Console.WriteLine()`.

Comment: "unpredictable" pretty well summarizes a classic race condition

Comment: In that article, there's "Because the default task creation options for the Task.Run overloads include TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, this example is functionally equivalent to the first example in the "Detached child tasks" section." which may suggest that `DenyChildAttach` is only the default and could be changed.. Interesting..

Comment: ..and of course there's no overload for [Task.Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.7.2) that would take `TaskCreationOptions` so the 'default' is actually forced and not configurable, so well, that's the answer all right!